# MySQL - Return distinct IDs where all rows for the same ID do not have specific field value

Tags: mysql

I have a query with two joins:

```
SELECT v.top_id, m.related_type
FROM content_v_table v
JOIN content_e_table e
    ON v.child_id = e.winning_child_id
LEFT JOIN content_media m
    ON v.child_id = m.child_id;
```

that returns this data:

TOP_ID  RELATED_TYPE
1            image
1            image
1            video
2            NULL
3            image
3            image
4            video
4            video
4            video
4            image
5            image

I would like to return the unique TOP_IDs which do not have a "video" value in the "RELATED_TYPE" column for any of the rows with the same TOP_ID.  In this case, the query should return these TOP_IDs:

2
3
5

Thank you!

Comment: `I have a query with two joins` ... nice.  Do we get to actually see this query?

Comment: Sorry, I did not think that was important.  Here it is:

select v.top_id, m.related_type from content_v_table v
join content_e_table e on v.child_id = e.winning_child_id
left join content_media m on v.child_id = m.child_id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this using aggregation by the `TOP_ID` to assert that no record in a given group has a video related type:

```
SELECT v.top_id
FROM content_v_table v
INNER JOIN content_e_table e
    ON v.child_id = e.winning_child_id
LEFT JOIN content_media m
    ON v.child_id = m.child_id
GROUP BY v.top_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN m.related_type = 'video' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can do:

```
with 
x as (
  my_query_with_two_joins
)
select distinct id
from x
where id not in (select id from x where type = 'video')
```